# How to find the standard deviation s of simple linear regression coefficients Alpha and Beta in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, statistics, linear-regression

I have data and I need to do a linear regression on the data to obtain

y=Alpha*x+Beta

Alpha and Beta are estimators given by the regression, polyfit can give me those with no problem but this is a physical science report and I need to give error estimators on those values

I know from statistics that standard deviation exists for simple linear regression coefficients.

How can I calculate then in Matlab

Thank you

Comment: The least squares linear fit is a statistic, it does not have error bars per say.  For instance, if you calculate the mean value of a bunch of data points does it have error bars?

Comment: look at cftool, it might be what you need

Comment: Do you need the standard errors of the regression coefficients `Alpha`, or are you looking to calculate confidence bounds on `y`? Do you have access to Statistics Toolbox, or just MATLAB?

Comment: I am not talking about error bars at all, I am talking about the SD of the estimators

Comment: @SamRoberts I am looking for the SD of Alpha and Beta and I do have access to the Statistics Toolbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second output of the `regress` command will give you 95% confidence intervals for the regression coefficients. Here's an example:

```
>> x = [ones(100,1), (1:100)'];
>> alpha = 3; beta = 2;
>> y = x*[alpha; beta]+randn(100,1);
>> [coeffs, coeffints] = regress(y,x);
>> coeffs
coeffs =
       2.9712
       1.9998
>> coeffints
coeffints =
       2.5851       3.3573
       1.9932       2.0064
```

Here alpha has been estimated 2.9712, with 95% confidence interval of between 2.5851 and 3.3573, and beta has been estimated as 1.9998, with 95% confidence interval between 1.9932 and 2.0064.

Comment: The standard deviation of the coefficients is in the fifth output, stats.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to use [LSCOV](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/lscov.html):

```
%# create some data
x = 1:10;
y = 3*x+randn(size(x))*0.1;

%# create the design matrix
A = [x(:),ones(length(x),1)];


[u,std_u] = lscov(A,y(:));

u =
       3.0241
    -0.070209
std_u =
     0.018827
      0.11682
```

Answer (score 0):

Or just use the relationship that the length of the 95%  Confidence Interval is 2*1.9654 standard errors so the standard errors in the example with regress above are given by:

> st errors = (coeffints(:,2)-coeffints(:,1))/(2*1.9654).

The number 1.9654 appears because of the normality assumption in the regress function